# How to count and group multiple properties values in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
[
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 4, ..., 'k_services': 3},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 2, 'f_security': 2, ..., 'k_services': 4},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, ..., 'k_services': 1},
  ...
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, ..., 'k_services': 3},
]
```

How to count multiple properties values, then grouping it, and save it in a new object, e.g.:

```
{
  'a_academic': {
      4: 0,
      3: 3,
      2: 1,
      1: 0
  },
  'f_security': {
      4: 1,
      3: 2,
      2: 1,
      1: 0
  },
  ...,
  'k_services': {
      4: 1,
      3: 2,
      2: 0,
      1: 1
  }
}
```

I'm able to do it using reduce and manually accessing the key, but only for one property:

```
let count = array.reduce((res, cur) => {
    res[cur.a_academic] = res[cur.a_academic] ? res[cur.a_academic] + 1 : 1;
    return res;
  }, {});

console.log(count);
```

Result:

```
{
  3: 3,
  2: 1
}
```

How to implement this efficiently so it works for all other properties, without manually accessing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an array of keys that you want to count and then use `reduce` method with nested `forEach` loop on `Object.entries` and count the occurring values for each of those defined keys.

```js
const data = [
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 4, 'k_services': 3},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 2, 'f_security': 2, 'k_services': 4},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, 'k_services': 1},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, 'k_services': 3},
]

const props = ['a_academic', 'f_security', 'k_services']

const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  Object.entries(e).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (props.includes(k)) {
      if (!r[k]) r[k] = {}
      r[k][v] = (r[k][v] || 0) + 1
    }
  })
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

To fill empty values in each object you would have to first find min and max values for the whole data but also for only defined props.

```js
const data = [
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 4, 'k_services': 3},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 2, 'f_security': 2, 'k_services': 4},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, 'k_services': 1},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, 'k_services': 3},
]

const props = ['a_academic', 'f_security', 'k_services']

const values = data.map(e => {
  return Object.entries(e)
    .filter(([k]) => props.includes(k))
    .map(([k, v]) => v)
}).flat()

const max = Math.max(...values)
const min = Math.min(...values)

const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  Object.entries(e).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (props.includes(k)) {
      if (!r[k]) {
        r[k] = {}

        for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
          r[k][i] = 0
        }
      }

      r[k][v] += 1
    }
  })
  return r;
}, {})


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a nested grouping by omitting `year` from the objects.

```js
var data = [{ year: 2019, a_academic: 3, f_security: 4, k_services: 3 }, { year: 2019, a_academic: 2, f_security: 2, k_services: 4 }, { year: 2019, a_academic: 3, f_security: 3, k_services: 1 }, { year: 2019, a_academic: 3, f_security: 3, k_services: 3 }],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, { year, ...o }) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            r[k] = r[k] || {};
            r[k][v] = (r[k][v] || 0) + 1;
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is to use the **value** of `cur.academic` instead of the key name. To better explain this, consider this

```
const obj = { alpha: 20, beta: 30, gamma: 40 };

console.log(obj['alpha']); // outputs 20
```

What you can do is this:

```
const array = [
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 4, 'k_services': 3},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 2, 'f_security': 2, 'k_services': 4},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, 'k_services': 1},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, 'k_services': 3},
];

const excludedKeys = ['year'];
let count = array.reduce((res, curr) => {
    // Select the keys you are going to use and exclude the ones you won't
    const keys = Object.keys(curr).filter(key => !excludedKeys.includes(key));

    keys.forEach(key => {
        res[key] = res[key] ? res[key] + 1 : 1;
    });

    return res;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the keys from one of your objects (excluding `year`), and then map each key to a tally array. For example, `a_academic` has the value array of `[3, 2, 3, 3]` which is mapped to `[0, 0, 1, 3, 0]`. Using this `total` array, you can use `Object.assign()` to assign its indexes to an object, which you can use for each group like so:

```js
const arr = [
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 4, 'k_services': 3},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 2, 'f_security': 2, 'k_services': 4},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, 'k_services': 1},
  {'year': 2019, 'a_academic': 3, 'f_security': 3, 'k_services': 3},
];

const groupArr = ([{year, ...first}, ...arr]) => {
  const ent = Object.entries(first);
  const gr = ent.map(([key, v]) => [v, ...arr.map(o => o[key])]);
  const maxN = Math.max(...gr.flat());
  const minN = Math.min(...gr.flat());
  
  const total = gr.map(arr =>
    arr.reduce((tally, n) => (tally[n]++, tally), Array(minN).concat(Array(maxN).fill(0)))
  );
  return Object.assign({}, ...ent.map(([k], i) => ({[k]: Object.assign({}, total[i])})));
}

console.log(groupArr(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Object.keys` loop for your logic to access keys dynamically.

```js
const array = [
  { year: 2019, a_academic: 3, f_security: 4, k_services: 3 },
  { year: 2019, a_academic: 2, f_security: 2, k_services: 4 },
  { year: 2019, a_academic: 3, f_security: 3, k_services: 1 },
  { year: 2019, a_academic: 3, f_security: 3, k_services: 3 }
];

let count = array.reduce((res, cur) => {
  Object.keys(cur)
    .filter(key => key.includes("_"))
    .forEach(key => {
      const obj = res[key] || {};
      res[key] = {
        ...obj,
        [cur[key]]: (obj[cur[key]] || 0) + 1
      };
    });
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```